# Deliver a notification with vibration, LED light, sound using FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the sample Firebase code from [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) to see if it works with my project.

I receive a notification when my app is killed or closed once the database child value changes, all is good, but how do I set the vibration, sound and led light blinking function using code from [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js)? Do I need to detect the notification with android or I have to implement it with the payload somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In the data portion of your FCM message add:

```
 ledColor: [215, 138, 138, 1], //show a blinking LED in ARGB format
```